# IDiffNavigator is gone in monaco editor v44

Tags: monaco-editor

Previously in v38 we use `const naviRef = useRef<monaco.editor.IDiffNavigator>()` to navigate among changes and it works well.

When switched to v44 the navigator class is gone. What's the current navigation API? I cannot find any in its documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: You better ask this in the [Monaco issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues).